# iOS: recreating countdown timers after clock change?

Tags: objective-c, ios, time, timer

I'm working on an iOS app that uses an NSTimer for a countdown. This is prone to user tampering: if, for example, the user switches out of the app, closes the app manually, changes the device clock, and comes back in, the timer will have to be recreated. Another scenario: the user locks the device, it goes into low-power mode (which requires timers to be recreated), and the clock auto-sets before the game is opened again. If that happens, I won't have an accurate way of determining how much time has passed since the app was closed, since the device clock has changed.

Tl;dr: countdown timers sometimes have to be recreated after a device clock change. How is this problem usually handled?

Comment: And before anyone suggests it: I've seen mach_absolute_time() bandied about, but a) it seems like a very low-level approach for a high-level problem, and b) since AFAIK it uses CPU ticks to measure time, I would imagine it's less accurate than the quartz clock.

Comment: Do you want to recreate the timer with the last known time, or do you want to start it from scratch?  If you want to recreate it with the last time, then perhaps you could save the time to user preferences when the app is about to change state, and read it from user preferences when the app comes back.

Comment: I'd like it to look as if the timer was ticking away in the background like nothing happened. Example: user switches away with 10s left and changes the time to 1 hour ahead. This takes the user 5s. When the user comes back, the timer should say 5s.

Comment: How accurate you need the clock to be? Generally you need to save the time, and amount of time left in the timer in functions like 'applicationDidResignActive' and create a new timer with this data on 'applicationDidBecomeActive'. The exact implementation shall vary on the accuracy needed.

Comment: It doesn't need to be super-accurate, just reasonably so — within a couple of seconds. I already save time data in applicationDidResignActive, but I have no way of measuring how long the program has been inactive if the system time changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you're relying on the system clock for accurate timing you're going to have troubles, even if the user isn't deliberately tampering with the clock. Typically clock drift is corrected by slightly increasing or decreasing the length of a second to allow the clock to drift back into alignment over a period of minutes. If you need accurate timing, you can either use something like `mach_absolute_time()` which is related to the system uptime rather than the system clock, or you can use Grand Central Dispatch. The `dispatch_after()` function takes a `dispatch_time_t` which can either be expressed using wall time (e.g. system clock) or as an offset against `DISPATCH_TIME_NOW` (which ignores wall clock).

Comment: I've heard about mach_absolute_time(), but since it uses CPU ticks instead of the system clock to measure time, wouldn't it be significantly less accurate? As for GCD, I'd like to retain compatibility with older iOS versions.

Comment: `mach_absolute_time()` is the most accurate timer you can possibly get. It's not some sort of measurement of CPU work (which doesn't make sense anyway, CPUs run off of a clock signal, not the other way around). You may be confused because `mach_absolute_time()` returns a value that is termed "CPU-dependent", but that doesn't mean it's not accurate or reliable. It just means it needs to be converted into units you can use.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification — I think I have some gaps in my knowledge about how timing works. Is mach_absolute_time() the "canonical" timekeeping function? In 4.2, there are three time.h headers defined, and Apple's "Miscellaneous Kernel Services" article (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/services/services.html) talks about several more timing functions.

Comment: That article is talking about functions for use within the kernel. You're not writing code that's executing in the kernel. `mach_absolute_time()` is the appropriate function here, though you could also use `CACurrentMediaTime()` if you want, as that function is based off of `mach_absolute_time()`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll probably go with CACurrentMediaTime() then, since it's nice to work on a slightly higher level of abstraction.

Comment: One more thing: would you happen to know how mach_absolute_time() (and other CPU-dependent time functions) relates to the CMOS battery-powered real-time clock circuit?

Comment: @Archagon: Sorry I don't know anything about the CMOS clock circuit

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, in regard to different systems of timekeeping in OSX (and consequently iOS):

> One way to measure the speed of any operation, including launch times,
>   is to use system routines to get the current time at the beginning and
>   end of the operation. Once you have the two time values, you can take
>   the difference and log the results.
>
> The advantage of this technique is that it lets you measure the
>   duration of specific blocks of code. Mac OS X includes several
>   different ways to get the current time:
>
> - mach_absolute_time reads the CPU time base register and is the
>     basis    for other time measurement functions.
> - The Core Services UpTime function provides nanosecond resolution
>     for    time measurements.
> - The BSD gettimeofday function (declared in `<sys/time.h>`) provides
>     microsecond resolution. (Note, this function incurs some overhead but
>     is still accurate for most uses.)
> - In Cocoa, you can create an NSDate object with the current time at 
>     the beginning of the operation and then use the
>     timeIntervalSinceDate: method to get the time difference.

Source: [Launch Time Performance Guidelines, "Gathering Launch Time Metrics"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/LaunchTime/Articles/MeasuringLaunch.html).

Comment: This is also a good reference: http://blog.airsource.co.uk/index.php/2010/03/15/quelle-heure-est-il/